# Replace the hardcoded value inside the index.html with value returned by a method call

Tags: angular, typescript, sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

please help me.
I have to replace the hardcoded value for 'data-smartedit-allow-origin' inside the index.html with a value that should be retrieved using a site configuration service.

By calling a method of this service I can get the value that should be used for the 'data-smartedit-allow-origin'.

Do you have any idea on how I can replace the 'data-smartedit-allow-origin' hardcoded value with the value returned by the service?
(if you need any more information please let me know and I will provide it)

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 ...
   <script
      id="smartedit-injector"
      src="webApplicationInjector.js"
      data-smartedit-allow-origin="localhost:9002"
   ></script>
 </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

**the service:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SiteConfigurationDetailsService {
  constructor(
    private readonly siteConfigurationService: siteConfigurationService
  ) {}

  public getStringValueForKey(key: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.siteConfigurationService.getConfigurationByKey(key).pipe(
      map(result => {
        return result.value.value;
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to replace the value in index.html, you can try generating the script through winref or renderer2.

First of all, you would need to remove the hardcoded script.
Secondly, in a component, create a function that creates a script element and populates it with same values except you will populate the `data-smartedit-allow-origin` value with the value returned by your service. 
Finally, call it in your constructor or any of the angular's lifecycle hook in order to inject it to the head or body.